# Add additional statistics for proposals in definition to Area 51 sidebar

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, area-51, statistics, definition-phase

The Area51 sidebar contains these useful tidbits during the commitment phase:

[image: users also committed to, committers active in, committer roles roles stats]

However, none of these are available in the definition phase.  They should be! "Followers also committed to", "Followers also following", and activity/roles stats would be useful when discussing whether proposals should be merged, predicting what the user base and community will be like, and choosing which proposals to follow.  Additionally, a "Committers following" statistic should be added to the commitment phase.

I understand that the roles are not known during the definition phase.  I could easily see this being added (probably as an optional parameter) after clicking "Follow".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition-phase sidebar now shows "users also following" and "followers active in":

[image]